# Making calculation from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, calculated-columns, calculation

I am trying to do two SQLite tables, one to enter data and another one to retrieve the calculated data.

First I want to let the client enter some REAL data and then calculate in the background and put the new data to the textview.

For now, I tried to retrieve it from one table.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String sSQL;

    sSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + DataContract.TABLE_NAME +
            "(" +
            DataContract.Columns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_WIDTH + " REAL, " +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_LENGHT+ " REAL, " +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_PRICE+ " REAL, " +


   //This is the data I want to calculate and put to a textview in a 
   //new intent

   DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE + " REAL)"; 




    Log.d(TAG,sSQL);

    db.execSQL(sSQL);



}
```

I have a Serializable class and I tried to calculate the data in this class.

```
private final String ProductName;
private final double ProductLenght;
private final double ProductWidth;
private final double ProductPrice;
private final double ProductTotalPrice;
```

Then I tried to calculate the data in getter method.

```
public double getProductTotalPrice() {

    return (getProductWidth() * getProductLenght() * getProductPrice())/1000;

}
```

However, I dont know how to put retrieve the calculated data back to the textview.

Should I create two tables or one table is enough for this operation ?

And also what is the easiest way to calculate data inside Java code and put it back to a column ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

> And also what is the easiest way to calculate data inside Java code
>   and put it back to a column ?

To do nothing (i.e. calculate the value when extracting the data and reduce the amount of data stored in the database)

To add another column for the calculated value would be a waste as you can calculate the value when extracting the data (into the cursor) e.g. :-

Assuming the table (called **myproducts**) is populated as follows (note no PRODUCT_TOTAL_PRICE column as it's not needed) :-

[image]

Then extracting it using the query :-

```
SELECT 
    _ID,
    PRODUCT_NAME, 
    PRODUCT_WIDTH, 
    PRODUCT_LENGTH, 
    PRODUCT_PRICE, 
    (PRODUCT_WIDTH * PRODUCT_LENGTH * PRODUCT_PRICE)/1000 AS CALCULATED_TOTAL_PRICE
FROM myproducts;
```

Will result in :-

[image]

You could have a method in your Database Helper such as :-

```
    public double Cursor getTotalpriceBtId(long id) {
        double rv = 0;
        String column_name = "totalprice";
        String calculation = "(" +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_WIDTH + " * " +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_LENGHT + " * " +
            DataContract.Columns.PRODUCT_PRICE + ")/1000";
        String[] columns = new String[]{calculation + " AS " + column_name};
        String whereclause = DataContract.Columns._ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor csr = this.getWritableDatabase().query(
            DataContract.TABLE_NAME,
            columns,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,null,null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst) {
            rv = csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(column_name));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
```

- The underlying SQL is similar to the example above. However, just the one column is needed.

> However, I dont know how to put retrieve the calculated data back to
>   the textview.

Something along the lines of :-

`yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(yourDBHelperInstance.getTotalpriceBtId(ID_OF_THE PRODUCT)));`

or perhaps :-

```
yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(yourproduct.getProductTotalPrice()));
```

Comment: Great. But this: `(PRODUCT_WIDTH * PRODUCT_LENGTH * PRODUCT_PRICE) * .001 AS CALCULATED_TOTAL_PRICE` would be slightly faster (since multiplications are faster than divisions). So multiplying by the precalculated inverse is faster.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two tables
after inserting the value into table you just create a function by below query

select sum(your column name) from yourtablename where condition on which basis you filter the data.